# Update information in PHP without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I hope they are well! I have a small problem, everything works perfect but it's not what I'm looking for, this function:

```
<script>
var previous = null;
var current = null;
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://www.casadelpana.com/api/v1", function(json) {
        current = JSON.stringify(json);            
        if (previous && current && previous !== current) {
            console.log('refresh');
            location.reload();
        }
        previous = current;
    });                       
}, 2000);
```

When updating JSON data, the data is updated at https://www.casadelpana.com/test but it reloads the entire page. I understand that it can be done with Ajax, I have not found something similar where I return the variables of my interest. How can I update data without reloading a page? Attached full code:

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Test
*/
?> 

<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Formulario</title>
<title>Probando AP.I</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var previous = null;
    var current = null;
    setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON("https://www.casadelpana.com/api/v1", function(json) {
            current = JSON.stringify(json);            
            if (previous && current && previous !== current) {
                console.log('refresh');
                location.reload();
            }
            previous = current;
        });                       
    }, 2000);   
</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php

$request = wp_remote_get( 'https://api.casadelpana.com/v1' );

if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
  return false;
 }
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );

         /* mostrar json original 
         print_r($body);   */
    $data = json_decode($body);

    /* mostrar json decode en PHP 
    echo '</br>'; 
      print_r($data);
      echo '</br>'; */


      $vbs = $data->items['0']->valor; // tomar valor del bolivar respecto al dolar
      $vars = $data->items['1']->valor;     // tomar valor del peso ARS respecto al dolar

    $tasaneta = $vbs / $vars;
    $tasacomercial = $tasaneta * 0.85; 

        echo 'Valor del bolivar: '.$vbs.'';
        echo '</br>';
        echo 'Valor del Peso ARS: '.$vars.'';
        echo '</br>';
        echo 'Valor de tasa neta: '.round($tasaneta,0).'';
        echo '</br>';
        echo 'Valor de tasa comercial: '.round($tasacomercial,0).'';



    // Hacer recorrido y obtener todos los valores.
  /* 
  if( ! empty( $data ) ) {

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $data->items as $item ) {
        echo '<li>';
            echo '<b>' .$item->nombre. '</b>: ' . $item->valor . '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
  */

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're already using AJAX here, what's missing is some code to take the data returned by the Ajax call and place it into your page - either by creating new HTML elements and appending them to the page, or by updating the contents of existing elements. jQuery and JavaScript have lots of functions you can use to achieve that which are very well documented, and there are hundreds of tutorials on the topic as well. It should not be hard to research.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your API is giving a JSON.

```
{
    "items": [{
        "id": "1",
        "nombre": "Bolivar",
        "valor": "3350"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "nombre": "Pesos ARS",
        "valor": "41"
    }]
}
```

Without location.reload(); you can do like this.

```
$.getJSON("https://www.casadelpana.com/api/v1", function(json) {
        current = JSON.stringify(json);            
        if (previous && current && previous !== current) {
            console.log('refresh');
            // this will write first item of json to body tag
            $("body").text(json.items[0].nombre + " : "  + json.items[0].valor);

        }
        previous = current;
    });
```

Comment: I have a script problem, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token + online 22. What can it be?

Comment: @IsaacMedrano my mistake. I wrote wrong syntax. Must be just +  instead of . +